# Browserify FullCalendar with external jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, external, browserify

I am loading jQuery from a CDN and this error occurs when I try to import [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) into my scripts:

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'jquery'

Here is my script:

```
'use strict'

import $ from 'jquery'
import 'fullcalendar'

$('#calendar').fullCalendar()
```

I'm running this command to transform my script:

```
browserify index.js -t babelify -x jquery > index.min.js
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id=calendar></div>
<script src=https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js></script>
<script src=index.min.js></script>
```

I have also tried [browserify-shim](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim) with `depends: ['jquery', 'moment']` but it does not make any difference.

I suspect that it is because the FullCalendar JS file has a UMD wrapper that does its own `require('jquery')` and `require('moment')` but I thought the external flag would be smart enough to detect this.

Any way I can work around this problem?

Update: This was a minimal example of what I am trying to achieve, however my actual code involves many more dependencies than FullCalendar, and all third-party dependencies are concatenated into a `vendor.min.js` file, separated from our code (such as `index.js`).

Comment: Did you try using [the expose global](https://github.com/thlorenz/browserify-shim#a-expose-global-variables-via-global) part of browserify-shim?

Comment: @zero298 The library just attaches itself to `$` without exposing anything I believe. I have gotten other jQuery plugins to work successfully with the external jQuery (either with or without shim), just not this one for some reason.

Comment: what happens if you change the script to `import $` instead of `import $ from 'jquery'`?

Comment: Is this at all related to the fullCalendar issue : https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/pull/222 which appears fixed in more recent versions?

Comment: @Anthony `import $;` produces a transpile-time error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token`. And I assume the GitHub issue that you linked to is related though I am using the latest version 2.6.0.

Comment: did you ever got this to work?

Comment: @Pasta Yes but unfortunately I don't remember what I did to get it to work

Answer (score 6):

I was able to get it working by changing `require('jquery')` in the fullcalendar factory to `$`.

Also, no need to use `import $ from 'jquery'` in your index.js file. It is already a dependency in the fullcalendar npm.

After running

```
browserify index.js -t babelify -x jquery > index.min.js
```

Edit the index.min.js file in the fullcalendar factory function where it reads:

```
else if(typeof exports === 'object') {
    module.exports = factory(require('jquery'), require('moment'));
}
```

to:

```
else if(typeof exports === 'object') {
    module.exports = factory($, require('moment'));
}
```

Alternately, you could make this edit directly in the node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js file.

I hope this helps!

Comment: This isn't exactly a viable option because my actual use case involves concatenating all third-party dependencies (with the exception of jQuery) into a `vendor.js` file, and it is also unreasonable to ask everyone on the team to modify a file inside node_modules every time upon install.